# How to create configurable property on an IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom class for my SegmentedPageViewController. This view controller contains an IBOutlet which is the segmentedControl. I created two methods to configure the height and font so that I can call these properties from my view controllers in prepareForSegue().

In my custom class:

```
func setHeightConstraint(height:CGFloat) {

  segmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(height).active = true
}

func setTitleTextAttributes(dictionary:[NSObject: AnyObject]) {
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(dictionary, forState: .Normal)
}
```

In my prepareForSegue method in other view controller:

```
segmentedPageViewController.setHeightConstraint(25.0)
segmentedPageViewController.setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

The issue I'm facing is that it crashes on the above "setHeightConstraint" method since the segmentControl is nil. How can I configure it so that I'm referencing the correct segmentControl?

Comment: Did you connect your iboutlet with your storyboard/xib?

Comment: yes I connected it

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in the segmented controller to just hold the value you want it to use, not an IBOutlet.  Pass your value to this new property when preparing for the segue and then have the target controller use that to set the constraint on its own outlet in viewDidload (or later).